# Can excel formulas be written in a non-nested format?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Does excel have an alternative method of writing nested formulas? For example, is it possible to write a continuation formula?

[image]

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense to me, but I suspect the answer is no.

Comment: No, you cannot refer to the same cell in which the formula is placed.

Comment: now if you have Office 365 you can use `LET`: `=LET(a,A3*B3,ROUND(a,2))`

Comment: @ScottCraner That's very handy! Thank you.

Comment: @Scott Craner I challenge your comment RE: "*No, you cannot refer to the same cell in which the formula is placed*" - unless I'm reading out of context (not sure I am) - here are a couple of examples: 1) row(),column(), cell() can reference same cell as function 2) offset() starting cell can refer directly to same cell as this function 3) sumifs({same col. as function}, {adjacent col. <> adjacent cell}) etc... 4) iterative calculation mode allows you to input *=A1* in cell A1 (without circular reference). 
Further, you *can* always do this but may create a circular reference as a result..

Comment: Yes you are correct on those example, but in regards to what the OP is asking it cannot be done with out circular reference. And circular reference is fraught with issues and is not recommended because the allowing of circular reference is app wide and not specific to the single cell, and it changes by user and must be routinely allowed. @JB-007 Also in regards to what is being asked here a circular reference would not work either.

Comment: Hmm @Scott Craner - I do not disagree with your view RE: circular references but, with due respect,  I beg to differ RE the specific question in hand - which need not entail / involve circular references - see references at bottom of my soln for practical applications that deal with 'circularities' provided scope and calc modes are administered / applied in appropriate fashion...

Comment: I second what @ScottCraner said - this approach is fraught with issues.

Comment: Results can be meaningful and purposeful in financial mathematics (future streams of fin. payments), biology (spread of virus, quite topical) - further - complex eqns/algorithms  can be solved in a unique fashion. The question did not request advice RE applications that may be outside the scope of one's expertise - merely "can it be done" - I have successfully implemented this and when done in a refined/specific scope for a particular purpose - the examples / references provided show practical output.  (Microsoft have included this functionality for the very applications I mention)..

Comment: @JB-007 yes you have provided an answer with an assumption.  It is a good and well thought out answer.  One, that I happen to disagree with.  I have stated why in my comment below.  I think it a viable answer and enjoyed reading it.

Comment: @ScottCraner - I have reverted.  We appear to be an impasse  - your challenges (which go way beyond scope of OP q) can be easily mitigated.  Not sure its purposeful for me to carry on bullet proofing - A) "it can be done" - tick.  B) "it has practical / purposeful applications (academic references) - tick - I know they are a headache in ordinary/routine applications - no dispute - one should not rule out use / value in maths/simulation etc. (workbook sharing aside) due to personal experiences/field of application.  Glad you enjoyed - appreciate your remarks in this regard.  have a good one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *indeed* input such a function. Further, functionality of the feature I describe (iteration) can be paramount to several specialist fields in academia (Actaurial, Statistical - simulations, Microbiology).  There have been numerous case studies, journal articles etc. on this application within Excel (referenced below).

In your example you add the product of the A3*B3 to rounded (2dp) value of itself --  set calculation mode to iterative with max iterations = 1 (manual or auto calc modes explained below) to yield in the first computation/iteration the desired value:

[image: Max iterations = 1]

[image: First iteration]

*Note: no circular reference issues!*

[image: Circular reference status]

Iterative calc options are deliberate : i.e. manual mode without 'recalc when saved' - every time you calculate the sheet/workbook (e.g. shift + F9 or F9 resp.(♣) this result is added back to itself (by definition).  Thus you will return values that increment by a constant 8.99 per below:

[image: Iterative calc results]

♣ *See below for nuances/additional info RE: F9 (workbook) vs. Shift F9 (worksheet) & manual vs. auto calc modes)*

**Generalising to other popular examples**

More generally, the ability to expand / represent what you refer to as 'nested formula' in continuation form depends upon the mathematical equivalence between the nested and 'continuation' representations.  As an example, consider the sum of the first 10 terms of geometric sequence with initial term = 100, constant multiplier = 1.02:

```
= 100 + 100*1.02^1 + 100*1.02^2 + .... + 100^1.02^10
= 1094.97
```

Using elementary mathematics this simplifies to the following:

```
= 100(1.02^10 - 1) / 0.02
(= 1094.97)
```

In turn, one can simply use the *FV* function (given this is analogous to a loan to repay the future value of a stream of 10 payment of 100, compounding at 2% interest:

```
=-FV(0.02,10,100)
(= 1094.97)
```

In the context of your question vs. iteration mode, you can automatically advance the iterative calculation for 10 iterations by setting calc mode to automatic (in which case the result increments by a further 10 terms of the geometric sequence every time the workbook is modified, opened or closed, or recalculated directly by pressing F9).  To see the calculation at each step of the iteration in auto calc mode simply calc the sheet alone (Shift +F9). RE: F9 vs. Shift F9 - the same holds true when in manual mode.

The key difference (as before) with manual is that this result will not automatically update whenever the workbook / worksheet is modified (as is the case with auto calc).

You could even set to manual with iterations = 1, and hit F9 10 times to see how sum of installments accumulate / progress over the period):

[image: Automatic mode to advance iterations]

With these settings, a similar function to the round formula you presented will achieve the summation of 100 to the product of itself and 1.02 exactly 10 times... giving the exact same soln as the 3 alternative representations above, viz:

[image: Various representations of same function/equation]

*Notes: inputs are custom formatted: types for cells C3, C4: `"initial term :" #` and  "constant ratio: "#,##0.00 resp.  See [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-and-apply-a-custom-number-format-6c308025-35da-4047-9481-c146a12063df) for further details in this regard.*

---

**Practical applications / other references**

RE: iteration - see [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/remove-or-allow-a-circular-reference-8540bd0f-6e97-4483-bcf7-1b49cd50d123) for technical detail RE: functionality/operation and [here](https://www.spreadsheetweb.com/excel-iterative-calculation/) for several usefil (incl. related/geometric + other) applications.

For VB manipulation you can specify # iterations using `Application.MaxIterations = 10` (or other desired #) - see [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-for-iterative-calculations.913039/) for instance.

---

** Academic / specialist fields of application**

Charting exponential decay / related applications:
[here](http://www.tushar-mehta.com/excel/tips/0203-iteration%20to%20animate%20a%20chart.pdf)

Simulation in assessing marketing risk [here](https://www.proquest.com/openview/c1e4d52000b9d540850c28d9162b1638/1.pdf?pq-origsite=gscholar&cbl=36534)

Optimisation in Excel [here](https://www.hec.ca/en/cams/help/topics/optimization_with_excel.pdf)

Numerical methods in mathematics using Excel [here](http://crawford.elmhurst.edu/classes/m342/2010S/sec7.1_excel_instructions.pdf)

Oxford Academic journals RE: various applications [here](https://academic.oup.com/teamat/article-abstract/12/1/22/1670502?redirectedFrom=PDF)

*Circular references have attracted a poor stigma due to the regular/standard  way tend to crop up.  However, when utilised in an appropriate, controlled manner, the above is a small sample of several highly useful applications that would be difficult to replicate without their use (in conjunction with iteration).*

---

Comment: Okay, now share this with someone else or open it on a different computer.  The formulas do not work and require the allowing of circular reference in the full app.  One cannot save or apply this setting to this workbook itself.  And sometimes even just closing and reopening the app will cause this setting to reset to the default. requiring every time on opening it the user must to go back in the settings and allow circular references.  You can always use vba in the Workbook_Open to set that setting, but if I opened a workbook that changed that setting for the whole app, I would be pissed.

Comment: Hi - not sure what the assumption is that you refer to in penult. comment.  Re sharing: flaws you are bringing into Q go way beyond the scope of the original Q - notwithstanding 'none-issues' - a) assume one could provide 'setup' documentation in context of email? b) If intention is to share 'carte-blanche' (odd for highly specialised/niche topic) - then basic VB should do e.g. Private Sub Workbook_Open(), .Iteration = True, .MaxIterations = 10, .MaxChange = 0.001, End With, End Sub.  If Q is now "what about my macro security settings" ... well, then you have me ! No need to use foul language.

Comment: sorry about the `pissed` I meant it no more than `I would be very upset` I was running out of characters and `upset` did not give enough importance.  as to assumption, The assumption I am refering to is that it is meant to be compounding.  I had assumed that the OP wanted to not have to refer to the same formula multiple times ie: `=IF(ROUND(A1*B1,2)>9.01,ROUND(A1*B1,2),0)` type of item.  Which is the assumption I was making.  <cont>

Comment: As to the other questions.  It all boils down to that using circular references can be avoided in 99% of the cases. Why go through the nightmare of having to teach people how to adjust their settings in an app just to make the formula work, when there are other alternatives that do not require it.  Again I am not knocking your answer.  I think that there may be some that need this answer. Some others may find it useful.

Comment: cheers.  Niche area - I know.  Interesting topic - have enjoyed sharing / debating views.  You have valid pts. re concerns - I realise/appreciate this..  99% frought with issues - agree through/through.  Caveat warranted in this regard. (PS - np RE: synonym for 'upset' - I see what you mean - could see myself feeling same ! :) )